# Render new fields depending on choice in Django

Tags: django, model, choicefield

I'm working on a Django project right now and when adding a Right model I want the form to look different depending on what is chosen in the attribute 'type'. Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
class Right(models.Model):
RIGHT_TYPE_CHOICE = (
    ('NR', 'Normal right'),
    ('TR', 'Timed right'),
    ('ToR', 'Timeout right'),
```

)

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="The name of the right. What does it mean?")
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="Description of the right. Not required.")
type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=RIGHT_TYPE_CHOICE, help_text="The predefined type of the right.")
```

I'm thinking some kind of logic in order to add new fields depending on what is chosen as 'type'. Can someone help me out? I searched the docs, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add extra fields to your model form, and then control the toggle of these using javascript.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Is there some way to do this without javascript? I have zero experience in JS.

Comment: No. What you're looking for is front-end logic and that requires JS.